# How to select multiple series in the legend - highchart - javascript

Tags: javascript, r, shinydashboard, r-highcharter

I would like to select multiple series in the legend like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t2MxW/21971/).

With help, I succeed to create the same thing on R but it doesn't allowed to select more than one serie at a time.

Because I'm on R, I use the shinyjs package. The javascript code is in jsCode.

The code :

```
library(highcharter)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

data_plot <- data.frame(categories = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                        serie1 = c(1563, 1458, 205, 695),
                        serie2 = c(562, 258, 17, 115),
                        serie3 = c(324, 654, 23, 987),
                        serie4 = c(123, 567, 234, 12),
                        serie5 = c(376, 88, 98, 123)
)

jsCode <- JS("function(event) {
if (!this.visible )
return false;

var seriesIndex = this.index;
var series = this.chart.series;

for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++)
{
if (series[i].index != seriesIndex)
{
series[i].visible ?
  series[i].hide() :
  series[i].show();
} 
}
return false;
}")

ui <- dashboardPage(


  dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard"),

  dashboardSidebar(),

  dashboardBody(  

    highchartOutput ("hc1")))

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  #Normal Chart
  output$hc1 <- renderHighchart ({
    Hch <- highchart(hcaes(x = Spring ,y = Ponctuation)) %>% 
      hc_title(text = "Graph",
               margin = 20, align = "left",
               style = list(color = "#FE8000", useHTML = TRUE)) %>% 
      hc_xAxis(categories = data_plot$categories, title = list(text = "Number 
 of spring",color = "#FE8000")) %>%
      hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Result", color = "#FE8000"))%>% 
      hc_add_series(name = 'serie1', data = data_plot$serie1) %>% 
      hc_add_series(name = 'serie2', data = data_plot$serie2)%>% 
      hc_add_series(name = 'serie3', data = data_plot$serie3)%>% 
      hc_add_series(name = 'serie4', data = data_plot$serie4)%>% 
      hc_add_series(name = 'serie5', data = data_plot$serie5) %>% 
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(events = list(legendItemClick = jsCode)))

    Hch})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, the only difference I had with the java exemple was that I had to put true in the return :

```
jsCode <- JS("function(event) {
if (!this.visible )
return **TRUE**;
...
```